# Error reading strings from cells

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub nationalityscript()
Dim i As Integer
Dim temp As Integer
Dim Country As String
Dim strEnd As Integer
Dim strComplete As String
i = 0
Do While i < 300
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim a As String

    strComplete = Cells(h, i).Value
    strEnd = Len(strComplete)
    k = 0
    Do While k < strEnd
        a = Cells(h, i).Value.Substring(k, k)
        If a = "," Then
            temp = a
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    Country = Cells(h, i).Value.Substring(temp, strEnd)
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Hi, This is my first day programming in vba so please go easy on me.

I am writing a **macro in excel** to focusing on column **h**. any string found in column h the code will go through, Identify the last part of the string after the last "," and then replace the string in that cell with the sub-string it got.

**I think this might be irrelevant to my question though because my problem is assigning the string in the cell to a new variable.**

My issue is with the line highlighted here.
[image]

The error I am getting is:

> Runtime-Error 1004, object-defined or application-defined error.

Comment: Please, next time use the appropriate tags. VB.NET is not VBA

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå- I'm curious on how you would use a web search engine to find the OP's answer. Could you show an example?

Comment: @pnuts- that's right, the OP shows a lot of effort in the question, Bjorn's comment was not nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is looking for some variable or token called "h".  As there isn't one, the compiler is complaining.  `Cells` takes integers for the row and column, not the column letters.  So if you replace h with 8 (the 8th column), it should solve this problem.

**Update**

Sorry, I think you also want `Cells(i, 8)` as the syntax is `Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)`.

Comment: Would there not be an error for `i` as well, can't have a row 0

Answer (score 1):

First, the value of row i in column j would be 
Cells(i,j).

Second, you need to declare h as a column or as constant ...

Third, I am not sure about looping variable declare as in this way

```
Do While CONDITION
      Dim a as string
Wend
```

I don't think it would work.